# Linux, find all files matching pattern and delete

Tags: linux

Looking to find all files (recursively) which have an underscore in their file name and then delete them via command line.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the safest and fastest variant:

```
find /path -type f -name '*_*' -delete
```

It does not require piping and doesn't break if files contain spaces or globbing characters or anything else that other constructs would choke on. The easiest rule to remember here is to [*never parse `find` output*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  And never `grep` on filenames if you want to do something with them later. You can do almost anything with `find` directly.

See also: [GNU `find` Manual – Deleting Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Deleting-Files)

Comment: In all these years I never noticed the -delete option. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This includes directories which are considered files. Some of the other examples using *xargs* will fail if the filename contains spaces.

```
find . -name '*_*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

If you only want regular files:

```
find . -type f -name '*_*' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Just a hint, if you use `\+` instead of `\;` your command will be faster since it [will substitute the name of *all* found files](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files) instead of calling `rm` one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, let's do this progressively.

As a first pass, this is just a simple exercise in passing a wildcard to the `find` command, remembering to quote it of course, and executing the `rm` command for every file found:

```
find ${BASE_DIR}/ -name '*_*' -exec rm {} \;
```

But of course that's dreadfully inefficient.  It starts up a whole `rm` process for each individual file.  So while we could take a short detour through `\+` that's not where we are going to end up, so let's take the shorter route and bring in `xargs` to batch up the filenames into groups:

```
find ${BASE_DIR}/ -name '*_*' -print | xargs rm
```

But that has two security holes.  First, if any filename found happens to begin with a minus sign `rm` will treat it as a command-line option rather than a filename, and generate an error.  (The `-exec rm {}` version also has this problem.)  Second, filenames containing whitespace will not be handled properly by `xargs`.  So a further iteration is to make this a little more bulletproof:

```
find ${BASE_DIR}/ -name '*_*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm --
```

And, of course, there are the interactive features of `rm` that you probably don't want:

```
find ${BASE_DIR}/ -name '*_*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f --
```

The `-print0` and `-0` options are not standard, but the GNU `find` and `xargs`, as well as the FreeBSD `find` and `xargs`, understand them.  However, even this is improvable.  We don't need to spawn any extra processes at all.  The GNU and FreeBSD `find`s can both invoke the `unlink(2)` system call directly:

```
find ${BASE_DIR}/ -name '*_*' -delete
```

As a last preventative measure to stop you doing more than you intended in certain circumstances, remember that the filesystem can contain more than just regular files:

```
find ${BASE_DIR}/ -name '*_*' -type f -delete
```

Answer (score -2):

`find . -type f -regex ".*_.*" | xargs rm -f`

**explanation**
`-type f` finds only files
`-regex ".*_.*"` selects only files that have an underscore in them
`xargs rm -f` then removes the selected file forcefully (never prompts before deleting)

Comment: To handle files with spaces: `find . -type f -regex ".*_.*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f`, but then it still doesn't handler directories